# Can a Docusign signer view and sign documents or just sign only?

Tags: docusignapi

Tell me if this is correct: suppose I have an envelope with a couple of documents that need signing and a couple that just can be viewed. The template is set up to place signing tabs at specific anchor text spots in the document. I use the same template for all the documents. Can I create just a signer for all these documents and they will not be asked to sign anything on the view only documents because there are no anchor tags to match up? There is no way that they would be made to perform some action on the documents to be only viewed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Recipient is of type [Signer](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/recipients#types) and have tabs assigned on an envelope then the recipient will not be able to add any additional tabs. This applies to the entire envelope, individual documents does not matter.

However if the Recipient has no tabs assigned then the recipient will have the option of [Free form signing](https://www.docusign.com/blog/quick-tip-tuesday-guided-signing-versus-free-form-signing/).

> Free-form signing occurs when no tags are placed on a document submitted via DocuSign. This means that the signer will be presented with a palette of signature options (Signature, Initial, Full Name, etc.) which can be applied to the document at will.

So for your case, if you assign the Signer a Tab on the first document then the Signer will not be able to add new tabs on any document.

Comment: My concern is that the user will be presented with the free form signing option and I want to prevent that. I'm using composite templates with template roles and the two recipients in the template are set to "Needs to Sign"

Comment: Signer will not be presented with free form signing as long as they are assigned atleast one tab in the envelope.

Comment: You can also consider turning on [Document Visibility] (https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/cdse-user-guide-advanced-sending-using-document-visibility) for your account. You will not be able to send envelopes with [free-form signing](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Free-Form-Signing-Not-Allowed-When-Document-Visibility-is-On)  when Document visibility is enabled in your account.

Comment: Signer will not be presented with free form signing as long as they are assigned atleast one tab in the envelope. - I did not know this. I'm so glad I asked this question. I can relax a bit now. Thank you so much CodingDawg. I feel better now.